How to interface with W65C51 UART
I want to build my own computer with retro-ic's. One of those ic's that I want to use is the W65C51 from Western Design Center. I am trying to connect it to a Arduino to learn how to interface with this ic, but I am not sure what to do with the PHI2 pin. From the datasheet, I get that it is used for data transmission between the Arduino and the ic, but is there more to it? Do I have to keep a steady clock on this pin or can I just pulse at random (When needed)?

@thebusybee These comments look like they form an answer. Could you copy them to the answer box, please?

The data sheet reveals some dependencies on PHI2:

Figure 7 on page 21 shows that DTRB and RTSB change their level on the falling edge of PHI2.
The same figure shows that IRQB is cleared on the falling edge of PHI2.

If you use any of these signals, you need to take this into account.
However, as table 4 on the same page says, there is no maximum cycle time or maximum pulse width. You can apply PHI2 as you like, as long as the times are not too short. It is not necessary to provide a steady clock.
Concerning too short pulses: The most Arduinos run at several MHz, so if you use the library DigitalFastWrite, you need to insert some delay. If you use the standard function, you're fine, as these are quite slow.

There is no minimum phi2 clock requirement for the W65C51. See page 21 of its datasheet. It says that there is no maximum phi2 cycle time nor pulse width.
(The question is totally valid as e.g. the NMOS 6502 itself has a maximum phi0 cycle time of 20µs as its internal registers are dynamic memory.)

This is saying what the o2 frequency can be, whereas OP asked if it has to be a continuous frequency regardless of if a bus access or not. I can see what you're getting at but I don't think it's an answer, more a reply.

I understood the OP's question as whether he has to do dummy read accesses to match a minimum frequency requirement. That is not the case as there is no minimum frequency requirement.

But the OP asks clearly "Do I have to keep a steady clock on this pin or can I just pulse at random (When needed)?". The answer has to be to the question asked, afraid this isn't that. Not sure where you got dummy read accesses from, there's nothing like that in their question.
